# Android - Camera Zoom not working

Tags: android, android-camera, android-canvas

I have created an app. In that I am randomly generating `latitude` and `longitude` on `GoogleMap` and passing that values to next page.. i.e. `CameraPage`. But, on CameraPage the pins are not falling properly as on map.. I have implemented the `camera-zoom` and other methods but, still not working..

Please check the screen shot..

**MapPage**

[image]

**CameraPage**

[image]

Is there any solution to zoom the pins on camera without external zoom controls??

It should zoom by default when CameraPage gets loaded..

**EDIT::**

CODE::

```
ArrayList<Point> props = new ArrayList<Point>();
            props.add(new Point(a_latitude, a_longitude, a_username));
            props.add(new Point(b_latitude, b_longitude, b_username));
            props.add(new Point(c_latitude, c_longitude, c_username));
            props.add(new Point(d_latitude, d_longitude, d_username));
            props.add(new Point(e_latitude, e_longitude, e_username));
            props.add(new Point(f_latitude, f_longitude, f_username));
            props.add(new Point(g_latitude, g_longitude, g_username));
            props.add(new Point(h_latitude, h_longitude, h_username));
            props.add(new Point(i_latitude, i_longitude, i_username));
            props.add(new Point(j_latitude, j_longitude, j_username));


    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setTextSize(30);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(DpiUtils.getPxFromDpi(getContext(), 2));
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);      


    mSpots = new Bitmap[props.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < mSpots.length; i++) 
        mSpots[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.google_pin_new);
```

**Point Class::**

```
public class Point {
public double longitude = 0f;
public double latitude = 0f;
public String description;


public Point(double d, double e, String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.latitude = d;
    this.longitude = e;
    this.description = string;

  } 

}
```

Comment: What do you mean? I think the zoom level of your map in the screen shot is different than that used to put the pins on the camera.

Comment: No. Its same in both the screen.. i.e. In mapscreen and also in camera screen..

Comment: Can you show some code? Specifically, we need the code that you use to put the markers on the camera. How do you decide on their screen coordinates.

Comment: Actually, there are 4 files..can u please give ur email-id.. Its relating to live project..so I can't share here.. :(

Comment: But other people might be able to help. Can't you just add the relevant code here?

Comment: Ok.. Let me sort it out..

Comment: Actually, from map page I am saving Longitude and Latitude in sharedpreference. and displaying it in camera page. will share that code.

Comment: and then? What do you do with the bitmaps?

Comment: drawing that bitmap on surface by using onDraw method..

Comment: and you are using the latitude and longitude. It will of course not work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41846/discussion-between-mitesh-and-sherif-elkhatib)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the longitude and latitude to draw your points.

Use the function [`toScreenLocation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection.html#toScreenLocation%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng%29). For example, the following line will return a [`Point`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html) that represents the coordinates where you should draw the marker that is on location.

```
android.graphics.Point p = mMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(location);
props.add(new Point(p.X, p.Y, a_username));
```